# model.js.coffee included but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm fairly new to ruby on rails development and I'm running into trouble including the auto-generated js.coffee files into my html.erb.

Essentially what's happening is that I can get my js to work in my show.html.erb file but only if I include the js directly in the html.erb file (i.e., in a script tag). I was hoping to tidy up the code by placing the js into the js.coffee file for the model. So I converted the js to coffee js and did just that. No luck.

Then I thought, we'll ok maybe i'm doing something wrong in coffee js - so instead I just created a model.js file and used regular js. Still no luck.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The thing is, I can see that the model.js file is being included in my html markup in both cases - it just seems to have no effect.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

model.js.coffee:

```
$ ->
$("#star-1").raty
  click: (score, evt) ->
    overall_field = document.getElementById("rating_overall")
    overall_field.value = score

  number: 5
  half: true
  precision: true
  cancel: true
  size: 103
  starHalf: "bell-half.png"
  starOff: "bell-off.png"
  starOn: "bell-on.png"
  target: "#hint-1"
  targetFormat: "Overall: {score}"
  targetType: "score"
  hints: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", null, "", `undefined`, "*_*"]
  targetKeep: true
  targetText: "0"
```

Comment: So your CoffeeScript is being converted to JavaScript and that JavaScript is being included in the page via a `<script src="/some/path/whatever.js">` tag but the JavaScript isn't doing anything, right? What does your CoffeeScript do? Is it wrapped in a `$ ->`? Which version of Rails?

Comment: thanks for responding. The js is essentially configuring [jquery raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty). And i did place the $ -> at the top of the coffee file, but again i'm new to ronr even newer with coffee. is there a closing tag -- that is $ -> opens the tag and does something close it at the end?

Comment: You could just have an indentation problem, what does the `.js.coffee` file look like?

Comment: Sorry - not sure how to do this in code format  $ ->
    $("#star-1").raty
      click: (score, evt) ->
        overall_field = document.getElementById("rating_overall")
        overall_field.value = score

      number: 5
      half: true
      precision: true
      cancel: true
      size: 103
      starHalf: "bell-half.png"
      starOff: "bell-off.png"
      starOn: "bell-on.png"
      target: "#hint-1"
      targetFormat: "Overall: {score}"
      targetType: "score"
      hints: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", null, "", `undefined`, "*_*"]
      targetKeep: true
      targetText: "0"

Comment: OK - disregard above comment - i added the js to my original post. sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just have an indentation problem in your CoffeeScript. The block structure of CoffeeScript is defined by your indentation so this:

```
$ ->
$("#star-1").raty
  #...
```

gets turned into this JavaScript:

```
$(function() { });
$("#star-1").raty({
  #...
});
```

so your raty config isn't contained in the document-ready handler. The result is that `$("#star-1").raty({ ... })` will run *before* `#star-1` is in the DOM and nothing useful happens.

Just push your code over one level:

```
$ ->
  $("#star-1").raty
    click: (score, evt) ->
      overall_field = document.getElementById("rating_overall")
      overall_field.value = score
    number: 5
    #...
```

and things should start working better. BTW, you don't have to backtick `undefined` in CoffeeScript anymore so this:

```
hints: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", null, "", `undefined`, "*_*"]
```

should be just:

```
hints: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", null, "", undefined, "*_*"]
```

Comment: Wow - so simple :) Thank you so much for spending time to help me get this working - I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

-Create a show.js file in the view page (where your show.html.erb file is present and place your javascript codes there.

- in controller don't forget to include format.js (which is by default created by scaffold).
- else give a try by placing your code in application.js file or show.js file in app/assets/javascript folder.